# How do I overwrite a column of characters in R with 1s and 0s?

Tags: r, if-statement, binary, data-conversion

I need to convert one of the columns of my data to binary values. I am trying to insert 0 if there is a blank space and 1 if there is a string of characters.

My data currently looks like this:

```
Name     Code
Bob      
Joe     f59tuc
Anna    
Kylie
Jill    hyt618
Ben     skt310
```

And I am trying to convert it to this:

```
name     code
Bob       0
Joe       1
Anna      0
Kylie     0
Jill      1
Ben       1
```

I tried this if statement, but get errors. I am new to R, and have very little experience with if-statements, while-loops, for-loops, etc -- so there may be some obvious mistakes in the code that I am not thinking of. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
if (df$code[df$code == ""]) {
    df$code[df$code] <- 0
} 
else {
    df$code[df$code] <- 1
}
```

Comment: The error is in using `if` as one might have been taught in SAS or SPSS. R has an `ifelse` function for processing vectors. `if` and `else` are best reserved for program control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `df$code <- as.numeric(df$code != '')` would be enough for this case.

If you really need to use the if else, then

```
df$code[df$code == ""] <- 0
```

would be enough for setting 0s, since `df$code == ""` will give you a vector of bools, and these can select out the entries you want to assign 0s to.

Comment: Just as long as we are clear that there could be many interpretations of the phrase "blank space" and that "" is really only one of them. If it is the correct interpretation, then one could also use `nchar(df$code+ != 0`. I would feel safe in checking that single space and double-space values did not exist.

Comment: You are correct in that by blank space, I meant "". I was originally going to type "", but I wasn't sure which was a better descriptor. Thanks for the clarity!

Comment: I used this line df$code <- as.numeric(df$code != ''), and it worked. Thanks so much!